# Inclusion of a set in a bounded domain

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\delta>0$, define
$$
\Omega^h:=\{x-h:x\in\Omega\},\quad\Omega_{\delta}:=\{x\in\Omega:d(x, \partial\Omega)>\delta\}
$$
(where "$d$" denotes the distance). I don't understand why, if $|h|<\delta$, then $(\Omega_{\delta})^h\subset\Omega$. Some hints?

Thank You

Comment: It's a bit tough to just give a hint, most basic topology tasks are solved by 'apply the definition' method. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I don't understand the way in which the hypotesis $|h|<\delta$ can help. I cannot write a formal proof. Some helps?

Comment: Sure. $\lvert h \rvert < \delta$ means that for every $x$ distance from $x$ to $x-h$ is less than $\delta$.

Comment: @mike239x Ok, I understand. But how can I use this information to prove that, if $x\in(\Omega_{\delta})^h$, then $x\in\Omega$? Thank You

Comment: Mb this will help: $d(x, \partial\Omega) > \delta$ means an open ball with radius $\delta$ and center $x$ lies entirely in $\Omega$.

Comment: @mike239x So, if $x\in(\Omega_{\delta})^h$, then $B_{\delta}(x+h)\subset\Omega$. How can I conclude that $x\in\Omega$?

Comment: Try showing that $x \in B_\delta(x+h)$.

Comment: @mike239x I have that $x\in(\Omega_{\delta})^h$ iff $x=y-h, y\in\Omega_{\delta}$. That is $y=x+h, y\in\Omega_{\delta}$. So $B_{\delta}(x+h)\subset\Omega$. To prove that $x\in B_{\delta}(x+h)$ we have to show that $|x-(x+h)|<\delta$ but this is true since $|h|<\delta$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yeah, that is it. Well done :)

Comment: @mike239x Thank You :)